# Adding biome support to procedural landmass generation tutorials

Tags: unity

I've spent the past week studying the [procedural landmass generation tutorial series](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLFt_AvWsXl0eBW2EiBtl_sxmDtSgZBxB3) and have been toying around with the [source code](https://github.com/SebLague/Procedural-Landmass-Generation).

The following is an example of the core Noise module he wrote. Essentially, it accepts some noise settings (seed, octaves, lacunarity, etc) for every "chunk".

I've been trying to figure out on my own how best to implement "biomes" but this is too different than noise systems I've used in the past (they handled octaves/etc internally didn't build those with chunk coordinates, etc).

I know I need different noise settings based on the biome, but I just can't figure out the best way to implement here.

My biggest dilemma is that this logic calculates the octaves/frequency/etc for the entire chunk but those values would be different for different biomes.

Since I need biomes to blend a bit (aka I don't want biomes limited to entire chunks), I need to either:

- Use different noise settings for every "coordinate" (which won't work since this code uses one noise settings for the entire chunk)
- Calculate the entire chunk once for each biome in it and then somehow "sum" biomes
- Ditch this noise entirely with something I'm more familiar with (FastNoise, LibNoise.Unity). I've tried this, but absolutely will not work with the mesh generation he built, so I'd need to rewrite that too.

  ```
  public static CoordinateProfile[,] GenerateCoordinateProfiles(int mapWidth, int mapHeight, NoiseSettings settings, Vector2 sampleCentre) {
      var profiles = new CoordinateProfile[mapWidth, mapHeight];

      System.Random prng = new System.Random(settings.seed);
      Vector2[] octaveOffsets = new Vector2[settings.octaves];

      float maxPossibleHeight = 0;
      float amplitude = 1;
      float frequency = 1;

      for (int i = 0; i < settings.octaves; i++) {
          float offsetX = prng.Next(-100000, 100000) + sampleCentre.x;
          float offsetY = prng.Next(-100000, 100000) - sampleCentre.y;
          octaveOffsets [i] = new Vector2(offsetX, offsetY);

          maxPossibleHeight += amplitude;
          amplitude *= settings.persistance;
      }

      float maxLocalNoiseHeight = float.MinValue;
      float minLocalNoiseHeight = float.MaxValue;

      float halfWidth = mapWidth / 2f;
      float halfHeight = mapHeight / 2f;

      for (int y = 0; y < mapHeight; y++) {
          for (int x = 0; x < mapWidth; x++) {
              amplitude = 1;
              frequency = 1;
              float noiseHeight = 0;

              for (int i = 0; i < settings.octaves; i++) {
                  float sampleX = (x - halfWidth + octaveOffsets[i].x) / settings.scale * frequency;
                  float sampleY = (y - halfHeight + octaveOffsets[i].y) / settings.scale * frequency;

                  float perlinValue = Mathf.PerlinNoise(sampleX, sampleY) * 2 - 1;
                  noiseHeight += perlinValue * amplitude;

                  amplitude *= settings.persistance;
                  frequency *= settings.lacunarity;
              }

              if (noiseHeight > maxLocalNoiseHeight) {
                  maxLocalNoiseHeight = noiseHeight;
              } 
              if (noiseHeight < minLocalNoiseHeight) {
                  minLocalNoiseHeight = noiseHeight;
              }

              float normalizedHeight = (noiseHeight + 1) / (maxPossibleHeight / 0.9f);
              noiseHeight = Mathf.Clamp(normalizedHeight, 0, int.MaxValue);

              profiles[x, y] = new CoordinateProfile(noiseHeight);
          }
      }

      return profiles;
  }
  ```